@dp.message have no attribute "nick"
Написал для бота телеграмм функцию для присваивания пользователю титула (ника), используя автоматы состояний.
код следующий
class give_nick(StatesGroup): #создаем класс состояний
    nick = State()
@dp.message(Command('givenick'))
async def give_nick(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    if not (await base_func.is_admin(message, True)): #здесь проверяем пользователя юзаещего команду на админку
        await message.reply(msg_errors.bot_not_have_permissions)
        return 0
    if not (await base_func.is_admin(message)):
        await message.reply(msg_errors.no_permission)
        return 0
    error = await base_func.check_command(message, "mute")
    if error:
        await message.reply(id=message.chat.id, text=error)
        return 0
    await state.set_state(give_nick.nick) #переключаем состояние
    iddd = message.reply_to_message.from_user.id
    global fn_n
    fn_n = message.reply_to_message.from_user.first_name
    await message.answer(f"Какой титул дать {iddd}?")
@dp.message(give_nick.nick) #а тут получаем ошибку о том, что @dp.message() не имеет аргумента nick
async def prisvo(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(nick=message.text)
    con = sqlite3.connect("database/database.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    have_nick = cur.execute(f"select nickname from nickname where tg_id = {idd}")
    have_nick = cur.fetchone()
    have_nick = have_nick[0]
    con.commit()
    con.close()
    if have_nick == None:
        con = sqlite3.connect("database/database.db")
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute(f"insert into nickname (tg_id, nickname) values (?,?)", (idd, message.text))
        con.commit()
        con.close()
        await message.answer(f"Теперь у {fn_n} есть титул {message.text}")
    else:
        con = sqlite3.connect("database/database.db")
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute(f"update nickname set nickname = {message.text}")
        con.commit()
        con.close()
        await message.answer(f"Теперь у {fn_n} есть титул {message.text}")

`
в итоге получаем ошибку о том, что у @dp.message нет аргумента .nick. при этом в этом же боте написал команду для вывода погоды, так же с использованием FSM, так же с одним состоянием, и все работает отлично(код ниже)
@dp.message(Command("weather"))
async def townnn(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.set_state(Town.town)
    await message.answer(f"{message.from_user.first_name}, введи город")
@dp.message(Town.town)
async def townn(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(town = message.text)
    owm = pyowm.OWM("062c637c640ac6e8a41529c2e9318c26")
    mgr = owm.weather_manager()
    observation = mgr.weather_at_place(f"{message.text}")
    w = observation.weather
    print(w.clouds)
    temp_dict_celsius = w.temperature('celsius')
    print(temp_dict_celsius)
    tempo = temp_dict_celsius["temp_min"]
    tempo = round(tempo)
    print(tempo)
    await message.answer(f"{message.text}:\nТемпература: {tempo}\nОблачность: {w.clouds}\nСтатус: {w.status}")

вопрос, следовательно такой: почему не работает и как исправить?


Вас не учили называть классы с большой буквы? К чему относится у вас give_nick.nick - к вашему классу give_nick или к его методу give_nick? Подумайте над этим. Впрочем, у вас весь код написан так, как нельзя писать программы, тут всё нужно переписывать, извините.

нет, не учили. я самоучка и полный новичок. спасибо за ответ:)

и после исправления по вашему совету, выдает ту же ошибку

Попробуйте явно указать параметр: @dp.message(state=give_nick.nick)

Также у вас плэйсхолдеры для INSERT есть, а для UPDATE нет. Стоит использовать параметризированный способ запроса везде для предотвращения инъекции.
Ещё SQL запросы пишутся заглавными буквами, кроме названий таблиц и самих данных. Название класса принято задавать с заглавной буквы и в другом стиле, не_через_подчёркивание, а ИспользуяСтильВерблюда

Ещё очень тяжело читать код, нет логического разделения строк через переносы строк и функции/методы названы произвольно. Я понимаю, это Ваш код, но если просите помощи, выкладывая большую его часть, то стоит всё же постараться форматировать его по стандартам читаемости, если не полностью по PEP8.

Ещё подчеркну, что Вы используете асинхронную библиотеку для бота, но также используете синхронную библиотеку для базы данных, что вызовет кучу блокировок и сильно уменьшит толк от асинхронности. В таком случае telebot подошёл бы лучше был бы проще, но это моё субъективное мнение.

Если вы что-то попробовали исправить в коде, но получили ту же (или другую) ошибку - добавляйте исправленный код в конец вопроса. Типа, я попробовал вот так, как мне посоветовали в комментариях - и тоже не работает. Это полезная информация. А, возможно, вы что-то не то исправили. Кстати, всё же - что вы имели в виду под give_nick.nick и где вы такой способ вообще подсмотрели? Сейчас это выглядит как поле nick объекта функция give_nick и такого поля у функции действительно нет. Его можно сделать, но это странный метод передачи параметра.

спасибо за советы и информацию, приму к сведению. проблему решил, действительно дело было в заглавной букве, а когда сказал, что проблема не исчезла, по ошибке оказывается и в имени функции поменял на заглавную букву и опять все спуталось. все исправил, работает. еще раз всем большое спасибо
